# How to disable certain Google Calendars from syncing with the stock Win10 Calendar app?

Tags: windows-10, calendar

Windows 10 keeps notifying me of birthdays and dozens of other useless events because it's synced *all* my Google Calendars. How can I disable some of those calendars from syncing with Win10?

It's got almost no options:

[image: win10 calendar settings]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can uncheck the calendars from Gmail that you do not want. This will disable notifications but will not disable syncing AFAIK.

[image: Calendar]

I just tested it by adding a fake birthday to the Birthdays calendar. I set it to alarm/notify me at 3:18 and it did not. Another test event in a different Gmail calendar worked.

Comment: Where'd you find these settings?? Edit...oh........on the left. I somehow missed that and went straight to settings.

Comment: Sometimes things hide in plain sight :P